# Online backup for Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, backup, cloud-storage

I've been a satisfied user of CrashPlan for cloud backups of my family's computers for many years, but now that Code42 is [discontinuing CrashPlan Home](https://www.crashplan.com/en-us/consumer/nextsteps/) in favor of their business-oriented offerings, I now find myself in need of a new home backup solution.

Unfortunately, neither of their suggested replacements appear to fit my use case, as Carbonite only supports Windows & Mac (not Linux) and CrashPlan Business uses a per-device subscription model that would drastically increase the price. Our current cost for CrashPlan Home is ~$12.50/month, so I'm looking for alternatives in a similar price range.

Any solution would have to support:

- Backups for two Windows machines (one laptop, one desktop) and one Linux desktop/server.

  - CLI is fine for Linux, but a GUI is preferred on Windows.
- Cloud storage for >250GB of data.

  - Unlimited storage would be best, and encryption is preferred but not mandatory. A "cloudless" solution would not be sufficient as I'm aiming for an off-site backup in case of house fire, etc.

Ideal solutions would also provide:

- Support for local backup to external drive or NAS.
- Retention of file history.

  - Unlimited history is not necessary, but something like a 30-day rolling window would be nice.
- Configuration for both idle and scheduled backups.

  - I currently run nightly backups for the Linux server, but continuous/idle backups on the Windows machines.
- Controls for limits on bandwidth usage.
- Reputation for reliability.

Comment: Unless it's a typographical error, it's great to see that it will be more than a year before the termination of the free service. A friend received an email with the same notification and same termination date, which reduces the chance it's an error.

Comment: @fred_dot_u It depends on your subscription period. My email said *To allow you time to transition to a new backup solution, we've extended your subscription (at no cost to you) by 60 days. Your new subscription expiration date is 31 Oct 2017.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have chosen [Cloudberry backup](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/), storing my data with [Amazon Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/). Glacier is designed to back up large amounts of data that you do not need to retrieve often, so perfect for backups.
I have tested backup and restore on a Win7 machine.

Costs:

- The Pro version costs $29.99 ex VAT (€33,72 incl VAT) per computer, with one year of upgrades, and an additional 20% annual maintenance fee if you want to keep receiving upgrades (you don't have to).
- [Amazon Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/pricing/): Storage $0.004 per GB/month (varies slightly with region), retrieval $0.0025 per GB to $0.03 per GB, and $0.025 per 1,000 requests to $0,01 per request, depending on retrieval type:

> *Expedited*: for those who are willing to spend a little more for higher speeds. You can get you data in as little as 1 to 5 minutes. 
>   *Bulk*: for those who want to limit expenses by sacrificing access time. It is perfect for planned or non-urgent cases, with retrieval taking anywhere from 5 to 12 hours.
>   *Standard*: the option with retrieval typical in 3 to 5 hours.

My initial upload and tests (including that expensive Expedited retrieval) cost me $5.88.

**A warning about costs** (added after using this product for over a month):
I had configured CloudBerry to run continuously on both me and my wife's computer. This resulted in 150000 requests to the shared AWS Glacier account, costing $10 in the first full month.
We are setting the backup frequency back to every couple of hours now ;-)

Cloudberry Backup has lots of features:

- Windows, Mac, Linux
- Many cloud providers (Amazon S3, Amazon Glacier, Microsoft Azure, Google Drive, Google Cloud storage)
- No proprietary data format and you can access your data using other Amazon tools. Supports all Amazon regions.
- Versions that backup MS SQL Server, MS Exchange and Oracle backup (more expensive)
- There's even a freeware version, but that's limited to 200 GB
- Real time or scheduled backups
- Local backup
- Versioning. Option to purge locally deleted files from the cloud e.g. after  30 days
- Optional compression and full encryption, nobody but you can see your file contents ('Trust no one'). You can even encrypt file names if you want.
- [Easy to install](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtyI2YS-TPE)
- Intuitive GUI; nicely multithreaded (I ran backups and restores together during testing)
- Mail notifications (always or on errors), event log entries.
- [Bandwidth limitations](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/cloudberry-backup-intelligent-bandwidth-scheduler/)

Note: **There is a 1 TB storage limit**, you can [ask a quote for more](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/update-storage-limit.aspx)

[Here's the FAQ](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup-faq.aspx), [here's the support page](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/support.aspx), and [here's the documentation](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/help/backup/).

You reliability requirement is hard to answer. Crashplan looked reliable too, and then they pulled the plug. The Cloudberry software shows maturity, and they have been around for some time.

---

For completeness, here are alternatives I investigated and rejected:

[Carbonite](https://www.carbonite.com/) excludes a lot of file types by default. I have all kinds of files scattered all over my data partition and I do not want to spend the time reconfiguring all that and potentialy miss files. I just want to tell the software to back up D:\ with the exclusion of some folders that I determine I don't need backups for. I would need a 'Plus' subscription if I want video files I'm working on to be included. Carbonite costs $75 per person per device per year.

Before switching to Crashplan we were clients at [Mozy backup](https://mozy.com/). I have looked at them again. It would now cost $120/year for only 250 GB total on max 3 devices (on a personal plan), plus $2/months extra for each additional 20GB. That seems to be out of the data ranges you specify, as well as mine.